# Integral of differential form and integral of measure

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the relations and differences between integral of differential form and integral of measure. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_forms#Relation_with_measures):

> On a general differentiable manifold (without additional structure),
>   differential forms cannot be integrated over subsets of the manifold;
>   this distinction is key to the distinction between differential forms,
>   which are integrated over chains, and measures, which are integrated
>   over subsets.

1. Isn't a chain a manifold, and therefore a subset of a manifold? Why
   is that "differential forms cannot be integrated over subsets of the
   manifold"?
2. Is integral of a differential form defined in terms of Lebesgue
   integral via parameterization of the chain, as like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_forms#Integration)

   $$\int_S \omega =\int_D \sum a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(S({\mathbf u})) \frac{\partial(x^{i_1},\dots,x^{i_k})}{\partial(u^{1},\dots,u^{k})}\,du^1\ldots du^k $$

   So can one say that
   integral of a differential form is not a different integration
   method from Lebesgue integral?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Related but not identical: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49641/1543

Comment: @Tim: A [chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_%28algebraic_topology%29) is neither a manifold nor a submanifold. Rather, it is a formal sum of oriented submanifolds, possibly mutually intersecting (or with other pathologies).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Differential forms cannot be integrated over *all* subsets of a manifold. You cannot integrate a 2-form over a curve, or a 1-form over a surface. More precisely: integration in measure space is defined over a $\sigma$-algebra. So if integration is defined on two sets $A$ and $B$, the integral is also defined on $A\cap B$. But the same is not true for integration of differential forms. Given a two form $\omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and take $S$ and $T$ be two smooth surfaces that intersects transversally. $\int_S\omega$ and $\int_T\omega$ make sense, but not $\int_{S\cap T}\omega$.
2. Generally a differential form, *by definition*, when taken in a local coordinate representation, is given by functions that are *at least* continuous. So in fact you *don't* need the machinery of Lebesgue integration: all the functions you are going to deal with can be treated with Riemann integration.