# How is an integral with respect to a Hausdorff measure defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

In [a reply by Corey](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49704/1281):

> For integrals of scalar-valued functions on unoriented subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, one can use the Lebesgue integral with respect to $k$-dimensional [Hausdorff measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49704/1281) $\mathcal{H}^k$. The line integral of a scalar function $f$ over a curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is then: $$ \int_C f \, ds = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f \, d\mathcal{H}^1,$$ where I assume that $f$ is defined to be 0 off of $C$.

A Hausdorff measure is an outer measure on the power set of a metric space induced from the metric. I know how an integral wrt a measure is defined, but I wonder how an integral wrt a Hausdorff measure is defined? Or more generally, how is an integral wrt an outer measure defined, if it exists?

Or is it an integral because $\mathbb{R}^3$ is measurable wrt the Hausdorff measure, and the Hausdorff measure is a measure on the set of subsets that are measurable wrt it?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: An outer measure gives you measurable sets, these form a $\sigma$-algebra and the restriction of the outer measure to the $\sigma$-algebra gives you a measure. The integral is then defined as usual.

Comment: @t.b.: Thanks! I just learned that from Wiki.

Comment: Also: Hausdorff measure is a *metric* outer measure, so the Borel sets are included among the measurable sets.  In particular, then, continuous functions are measurable for this measure.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Choquet integral, that is an integral with respect to a monotone set function, to define the integral with respect to a Hausdorff outer measure.